# Possible XCode Analyzer bug when an init method/argument contains the word "delegate"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, reference-counting

I'm in XCode 5.1.1 and not using ARC.

When I add the word `delegate` to the end of any argument of an `init` method, XCode's Analyzer doesn't complain if you alloc it without releasing it.

The example below shows this behaviour. If you change `initWithDelegate` it to `initWithDelegat` (without the `e` on the end) then the Analyze behaves as expected.

```
@interface mrTest : NSObject
  -(id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate;
@end

@implementation mrTest
  -(id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate {
      self = [super init];
      return self;
  }
@end

-(void)example {
    mrTest * t = [[mrTest alloc] initWithDelegate:nil];

    // (just calling a method here so there are no build warnings)
    [t toggleItalics:nil];

    // Should complain that it's not being released, also doesn't complain if you uncomment this line
    //[t release];
}
```

It's not like it's somehow adding `autorelease` because that should complain when you do uncomment the `[t release];` line.

It even lets you get away with over-releasing it like this...

```
-(void)example {
    mrTest * t = [[[[mrTest alloc] initWithDelegate:nil] autorelease] autorelease];

    [t release];
    [t release];
    [t release];
    [t release];
}
```

Interested to know if anyone has an explanation or has experienced this before?

Comment: Wait awhile to see if anyone has a fix / explanation but if you've found a bug (and you seem to have an example already) then please report it to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a deliberate decision of the Clang static analyzer, as can be seen in
the source code

http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/RetainCountChecker_8cpp_source.html

```
01424   // If one of the arguments in the selector has the keyword 'delegate' we
01425   // should stop tracking the reference count for the receiver.  This is
01426   // because the reference count is quite possibly handled by a delegate
01427   // method.
```

It is also explained in the history

https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=158532

> [analyzer] RetainCount: don't track objects init'd with a delegate
>
> We already didn't track objects that have delegates or callbacks or
>   objects that are passed through void * "context pointers". It's a
>   not-uncommon pattern to release the object in its callback, and so the
>   leak message we give is not very helpful.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I didn't even realise it was an open source tool. Much appreciated squire